# Where is `onconnect` event in express?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Using "express" I've set this middleware:

```
app.use(function(request, response, next) {
    console.log(request.headers["user-agent"]);
    // etc.
});
```

so that on every request the `user-agent` header of it is shown in the console.
But you now what a mess `user-agent` could be:

> Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 7.1.1; Nexus 5X Build/NMF26F) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.59 Mobile Safari/537.36

and I really want to output the header once per connection – and NOT on each request.

How would I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

each request to an HTTP stack (server) establishes a new connection every time.. this is how HTTP protocol works

EDIT:

if you need to keep track of visitors you can use cookies or better yet sessions. Those will be transmitted to you with each request and when you don't find any attached you know that this is a 'new connection'

you can use [express-session](https://github.com/expressjs/session) for this purposes

Comment: I believe, there is something interesting with `"connection" : "keep-alive"`

Comment: mdn states that this is non standard... and frankly I do think that sessions are more appropriate in your situation and supported by all modern browsers

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that this is exposed in `express`, which is a good thing, because the last thing you want to deal with is handling HTTP 1.1 keep alive's yourself.

I would log the `user-agent` on a request that happens one time, maybe on a user authentication request or something of the sort.

Edit: To expand on the second part, one of the standard auth flows could be as follows:

1. User posts credentials
2. Server gives back a token
3. User uses token to access API

Thus, you could log the `user-agent` when the user gets a token, and log the token in every other request. This way you could easily search your log files for the user agent in the initial authentication request. This token could be a session ID, using a package like [express-session](https://github.com/expressjs/session), or a more robust authentication token.

You could also store that `user-agent` value in a session object server side once the user has authenticated, and add middleware that logs the session in a `trace` log on every request. This way you could enable logging of the session on every request and see the `user-agent` there if required.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Please, clarify the second part, I didn't get the point.

Comment: Oh, I've got it. You're talking about one "kinda special" user's request, which happens by-design no more than once, correct?

Comment: Yup! I've expanded on the description a bit.